# Issue about embedding swf in PHP and URLloader

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash, embed

I have a swf, coded in AS3, loading some variables from a php file.

When I run the swf embedded in html (or locally published in Flash), everything works fine. However, when embedding the same swf with the same code to a php, the URLloader fails.

I need to use php, to make the embedded swf dynamic (as to say, it should pass some dynamic vars to the swf in the end)

Looking for hours right now to solve it, but no idea :-/

Thanks for any kind of idea and help!

Comment: Can you post error message or reason why URLLoader fails?

Comment: Problem is, that in the flash environment it works, so no error is traced. Embedded in htl, too. Just not when embedded in a php-file, so i cant use a trace. Any idea what as3 code to insert to put an error at least to a textfield to see anything?

Comment: What about attaching listeners for io error and security error? See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html.

Comment: Added some listeners and outputted to a textfield to see it in the browser. Results are the following:

+++ Local in Flash and embbeded in HTML

openHandler: [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]

progressHandler loaded: 54 total: 54

httpStatusHandler: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=0 responseURL=null]

completeHandler data: opnSubjectLbl=Test&myStatus=ok%27%3Becho%20%24str%3B%3F%3E&%3C%3F%20%24str=%27

Comment: +++ Embedded in PHP

openHandler: [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]

progressHandler loaded: 31 total: 31

httpStatusHandler: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=200 redirect=false responseURL=null]